# Non oriented graph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the second number in the picture? First is count of nodes. Third is count of edges. But I can not figure out what is second. Thanks
[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2WuE.png)

EDIT:
The correct answer is based on the results for A)

Comment: The maximum degree fits all of the examples, but there's no $(7,5,9)$ answer to the multiple choice

Comment: That's what I thought...

Comment: It's not longest cycle, minimum degree, or coloring number

Comment: It's also neither the size of the smallest vertex cover or edge cover. It's also not the clique number...

Comment: Given that the first and third component were so elementary, I wouldn't expect that the problem intended the middle component to be anything very sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the given pattern, it's possible (i.e., it's consistent with the given data) that the middle component is the number of planar regions (including the unbounded region), hence, based on that assumption, choice A works.

Algebraically, one can apply Euler's formula:
$$V - E + F = 2$$

For the first graph, we get $8 - 11 + 5 = 2$.

For the second graph we get $6 - 8 + 4 = 2$.

For the third graph, assuming choice A, we get $7 - 9 + 4 = 2$.

Comment: The correct answer is based on the results for A)

Comment: Now edited to (possibly) fix the error.

Comment: I like your new answer, and think it is correct.